# Windows Registry Shows Windows 10 Pro Despite Running Windows 11 Pro

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-11, windows-registry

My laptop is running on Windows 11 Pro, and the system settings indeed confirm that it's running Windows 11 Pro. However, when I use PowerShell to query the registry for the Windows version `powershell Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name ProductName`, it shows `Windows 10 Pro`.

I've verified multiple times that the system settings indeed show `Windows 11 Pro` Could there be a reason why the registry isn't reflecting the correct Windows version? Why is that happening and how can I ensure that the registry reflects the accurate Windows version?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Windows system settings vs. PowerShell command
[image]

Comment: FWIW, Windows 11 Pro installed into a virtual machine also reports "Windows 10 Pro", so it isn't a case of something being left behind during an upgrade.

Comment: `powershell Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' -Name ProductName` is not the command that will tell you the windows version. That is appropriately `winver`. That powershell command just shows you the contents of a key in the registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My cleanly-installed Windows 11 also shows this same value in
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`.
The fact that your Windows 11 is an upgrade shouldn't matter.

The fact is, Windows 11 and 10 are counted internally as the same
version.
See the article
[Windows 11 Is Just Windows 10 in Disguise](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-windows-10-in-disguise/).

The title of this article is a bit misleading, but the main differences
between Windows 11 and 10 are internal and are not visible.
Windows 11 supports natively the new Intel CPU architecture of
Efficiency and Performance cores.
The rest of the changes are mainly in the user interface.

This registry value was just forgotten when Windows 11 was crafted.
You may signal it to Microsoft via the Feedback Hub, but this has
no real significance or adverse effect on Windows.